# Migration from TFS 2015 to Azure Devops Services

Tags: migration, tfs-2015, azure-devops-services

Can i migrate from TFS 2015 to Azure Devops Services without upgrading TFS to other/latest version, if possible please do provide related documents.

Answer (score 0):

This handy image from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020) will help

[image]

Yes, you can go from 2015.x to 2020.x

They also provide this note/warning

> Before you upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2020
> When upgrading your on-premises deployment to Azure DevOps Server 2020 you should be aware that upgrade from TFS 2015 and later versions are only supported. If you are using TFS 2013 or earlier versions, you need to upgrade to TFS 2015 first.